# Speaker pop / crackle when SBC connects to WiFi

Tags: audio, pwm, noise, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm using a Raspberry Pico to detect movement and play a sound via an amp & speaker. At certain intervals the Pico attempts to connect via WiFi to send and receive data.

However, when attempting to connect to a WiFi network there is a pop and crackling sound from the speaker. Once connected to the WiFi there is no further unwanted noise. My assumption is this is due to the WiFi module on the Pico suddenly increasing current draw.

If my assumption is correct, how do I go about mitigating this? If my assumption is wrong, what else could be the problem?

Also note: the switch on the battery. The circuit can also be powered by the Pico when plugged in to USB.

[image]

Comment: What’s your capacitor decoupling situation? What does your layout look like?

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, but I'm kinda new to all this electronics tinkering. What do you mean by capacitor decoupling?

Comment: Capacitors between Vout and ground. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor

Comment: Ah yes, I did find an article which led me to try a 220uf 10v capacitor between Vout and ground. It didn't seem to make much difference.

I don't know where to start in calculating what I should be using.

Comment: 220uF --> most probably Aluminium, therefore bad at high frequencies, put a 100 nF ... 470 nF ceramic capacitor parallel as well - no matter what ceramic type.
And audio is tricky, ground problems can cause it too. [A star ground (and power supply)](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2020-what-is-a-star-ground-layout-and-why-do-you-need-it) could help - then place the decoupling capacitors at the star point - or towards each load.

Comment: WiFi operates at few GHz, so unintended rectifying of these high frequency electromagnetic waves could occur in the audio circuit, therefore [shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding) the audio amplifier with a closed metallic case, connected to ground - or try to move away the WiFi antenna first - double distances, only 1/4th of problems...

Comment: Please show placement and board layout with a photo.